# OpenGL edges of textures are black

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, texture-mapping, cinema-4d

Here are two photos:

[image: Close up shot]

[image: Far shot]

When I move away from my textured object (the object is textured but its all white) dark lines appear on the edges. I think it is because of the pixel border on the texture that is separating the faces. It does not happen in the middle of the squared faces even though they are textured triangles so i'm a little confused. For some reason I cant upload the texture because its saying "For security reason, framing is not aloud" which I don't understand but the texture it basically some white squares separated by a 31-32 black border. The texture was baked in Cinema4D and the UV coordinates where exported with the object in a COLLADA 1.4 file. I'm not sure what is happening.

Info: Using FreeGlut and Cinema4D.

Comment: Are you using cubemap? Try setting texture wrapping to `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`.

Comment: I'm not sure what cubemap is. I'm new to texturing. I tryed GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE but it did not change anything

Comment: No i am not using a cube-map if you are referring to a "skybox" type thing

Comment: I would experiment first; changing the texture edges to another color, green perhaps, or make the background green. Unsure what you meant by 31-32 black board (31-32 pixels wide?) but eliminating whether its the background or the texture board would be a decent first step. Are you texture cords setup for full texture view?

Comment: Yes I was talking about the pixel border being 31-32 pixels wide. I changed it to pink and it had the same effect but the lined edged where pink. I'm guessing it is a mipmap issue like maxwellb said.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a mipmapping issue to me - your black borders are bleeding into the squares when the textures get downsampled. You might try using the atlas tools from nvidia here: http://www.nvidia.com/object/texture_atlas_tools.html to generate better mips.

Comment: I'm not sure what this program does. Could you explain abit please?